# No Stderr in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm try to view logs for an App Engine instance. stderr is not available in the dropdown. Only stdout, nginx.request, nginx.error, nginx.health_check, vm.events, vm.syslog and activity.

Did this get disabled somehow? It's available in other projects. I didn't setup the project and have no idea where to look.

Answer (score 0):

This `stderr` entry should appear unless it is used, as well as other entries in the same drop-down menu. I have experienced it various times myself and this is not unusual.

### Troubleshooting:

Check if the if the application is actually writing into `stderr`. Use this filters with the time span set to `No limit` to see if there are any logs.

```
resource.type="gae_app" resource.labels.module_id=[YOUR_SERVICE_ID]
resource.labels.version_id=[YOUR_APP_VERSION]
logName="projects/[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fstderr"
```

### Workaround:

You can print an error into the stderr with the tools provided by your language of choice and then after a short while the entry should appear.

Comment: In case anyone else is having this problem... I went to stdout, then changed stdout to stderr in the url... And now it shows up. It was full of errors dating back a week.

Comment: Hi @HornetBot, it looks like my answer worked out for you. Could you accept it so that every one can see that your question is answered? Thanks.